# How do I use one repository as a parent repository?

Tags: git

Not sure if the title is worded right, but

I have `repo-A` and `repo-B`

In B I have set up A and B as remotes.
Let's say B is an extension of A with some additional files and I want to periodically update B with changes from A but not push the additional B files to A

Is this possible. What is the best way to do this

Comment: "In B I have set up A and B as remotes" I read this as B is its own remote. That doesn't make sense. Typo? Anyhow, what you're describing can be done better with a branch. Do they have to be separate repos?

Comment: @Schwern: it should not be a typo. Why does it not make sense? I do not want branches in this case. It is complicated :) Think 'community edition' and 'premium edition'

Comment: I think you mean "in my local repository I have set up A and B as remotes". Maybe you should explain what you did using git commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a specific requirement to have separate repos, what you're describing is better done as a branch. B is a branch of A. Update B as any other branch with `git merge A` or `git rebase A`, whichever you like.  From hereon out I'll assume merging. Here's what that would look like with merging.

```
 1 - 2 - 3 - 6 - 7 - 10 - 12 - 13 [A]
          \       \               \
           4 - 5 - M - 8 - 9 - 11 - M - 14 [B]
```

If they must be separate repositories, you do the same thing but with remote branches. You might use this when you're extending a project you have no direct control over. To make things a little clearer, let's call A "upstream" and B is your repository. A is upstream of B. B only ever pulls from upstream, it never pushes back.

Set this up by first cloning A, then rename `origin` (which is A) to `upstream`.

- `git clone A`
- `git remote rename origin upstream`

Then add a new origin where you want to store your modifications remotely and push to it.

- `git remote add origin <url to your remote>`
- `git push origin`

Now you have this. Note that all three branches point to the same commit.

```
1 - 2 - 3 [master] [origin/master] [upstream/master]
```

Do your work normally, commit as normal, and push to origin. Here's after two new commits and a push.

```
1 - 2 - 3 [upstream/master]
         \
          4 - 5 [master] [origin/master]
```

When you want to update, first `git fetch upstream`. This will not alter your local branches, it will only update your copies of the upstream ones. Let's say upstream's master branch has two new commits.

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 6 - 7 [upstream/master]
         \
          4 - 5 [master] [origin/master]
```

And then merge like any other branch: `git merge upstream/master`.

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 6 - 7 [upstream/master]
         \       \
          4 - 5 - M [master] [origin/master]
```

You can do this in a single step as `git pull upstream master`.

Continue to do this and you'll wind up with the same thing as if you'd branched.

```
 1 - 2 - 3 - 6 - 7 - 10 - 12 - 13 [upstream/master]
          \       \               \
           4 - 5 - M - 8 - 9 - 11 - M - 14 [master] [origin/master]
```

The important things are:

- Remote branches are just branches.
- Pull from upstream: `git pull upstream`
- Push to origin: `git push origin`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it very simple:

> In B I have set up A and B as remotes.

**This is exactly what you had to do**

You simply need to add any number for remotes to your project and use them in any way you like to. (push to 1 and pull from the other one etc).

The remotes are the urls which your repository can talk to and you decide how you wish to use them.

- Clone the original repo
- Add new remote `git remote add <origin2> <url2>`
- Use the code from both the repositories inside a single repo

Now you can pull and merge the branches from the 2 remotes and have the code of both of them in a single repository.

As you can see in the image below you will have 2 repositories  which builds up your big repository.

```
# clone first repository
git clone <repo1>

# add remote 
git remote add <remote2> <url2>

# display the list of all the remotes
git remote -v
```

---

> > and I want to periodically update B with changes from A but not push the additional B files to A

All you have to do at this point is simply to pull changes from A to be

```
# make sure you are on the branch from repository B
git pull origin A <branch>

# now you have all the changes from A in your B branch
```

---

[image]